# How can I remove a value from a specific key in YAML with Python?

Tags: python, yaml

I have successfully worked out the addition of a value to a key in YAML with Python, and started to work on the reverse of it with reference to the code for addition. Here is my proposal of how the code work:

```
connected_guilds:
- 1
- 2
```

after the code is ran, the YAML file should be changed to:

```
connected_guilds:
- 1
```

Here is my code, however it didn't work, it ended up completely wiping out and the remaining is the `-1` in the first YAML example I enclosed.

```py
with open('guilds.yaml', 'r+') as guild_remove:
    loader = yaml.safe_load(guild_remove)

    content = loader['connected_guilds']

    for server in content:
        if server != guild_id:
            continue
        else:
            content.remove(guild_id)

            guild_remove.seek(0)

            yaml.dump(content, guild_remove)

            guild_remove.truncate()
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out :D

Comment: Don't export the array (`content`), export the dictionary (`loader`) instead. Try `yaml.dump(loader, guild_remove)`

Comment: Isn't `content` also a dictionary?

Comment: No, here `content = loader['connected_guilds']`, in your YAML file `connected_guilds` is a list, so `loader['connected_guilds']` will give you a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to reimplement searching for the item to remove when Python already provides this to you:

```py
with open('guilds.yaml', 'r+') as guild_remove:
    content = yaml.safe_load(guild_remove)
    content["connected_guilds"].remove(guild_id)
    guild_remove.seek(0)
    yaml.dump(content, guild_remove)
    guild_remove.truncate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution(with reference to the addition code):

```py
with open('guilds.yaml', 'r+') as guild_remove:
    loader = yaml.safe_load(guild_remove)

    content = loader['connected_guilds']

    for server in content:
        if server != guild_id:
            continue
        else:
            content.remove(guild_id)

            guild_remove.seek(0)

            yaml.dump({'connected_guilds': content}, guild_remove)

            guild_remove.truncate()
```